# Store TableView selected Row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view, I want to change selected table view selected cell color, and cell color not changed when scroll table view. there is my code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath 
indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  let selectCell = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        self.selectedCell.append(selectCell!)
 for i in selectedCell
        {
            if(!(i .isEqual(indexPath)))
            {
                let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(i)! as UITableViewCell

                currentCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
            }
        }
```

that's code crash when scroll table view.

Comment: Make a variable which will store the current indexpath.row on didSelectRowAtIndexPath on selection. Now check inside cellForRowAtIndexPath for current  indexpath.row. If the stored  indexpath.row is matching then change the color.

Comment: You need to change all the selected index color???

Comment: If you need to change all the selected row color, then save the selected index in an array in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method and checked in cellForRowAtIndexPath method that the index path is there in the array or not and handle accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems very strange to me. you don't need to set the background color of all other cells each time one is selected. Define your `celectedCells` as dictionary of type `Int:Bool` so you can set it to `true` for each `indexpath.row` like this:

```
var selectedCells = [Int: Bool]()

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        selectedCells[indexPath.row] = true
    }
}
```

and then in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method check that dictionary to set the backgroundColor, like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("YourCellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    if selectedCells[indexPath.row] == true {
        // Color for selected cells
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    } else {
        // Color for not selected cells
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
    //Rest of your Cell setup

    return cell
}
```